# Trying to locate my picture to the top right corner of my webpage using PhP script

Tags: html, css

I am new to writing PhP script and I am trying to locate my picture to the upper right corner. This is the code I have for the upload,

```
<div id="pic"><img src="HAB.jpg"></img>
```

Is there an easy way to do specifiy where to put a picture on my webpage?

Comment: You should do some reading/research on CSS.

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use css and apply it to the div

```
#pic
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DIVs with the id linked to a CSS style (as described above) is a good way.
I like a more structured solution and tend to use tables to position output. e.g.:

```
<?php
// some PHP code here
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
// some more php code
$imgfilename="./HAB.jpg";
?>
</head>
<body>
<table align="right" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="right">
<?php
  echo "<img src=\"${imgfilename}\" width=\"200\">\n";
?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: PHP is server side scripting - so all PHP is executed before the resulting output is passed to the client browser engine.
So we use can use the PHP to dynamically change the resulting HTML script.

Don't know if this is the kind of answer you were looking for but give me more details and I may be able to help.

Comment: essentially i have just a blank web page and i want this picture to be in the top right hand corner of the page.